# Decode BIN File to JSON File, Protocol buffer, Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, binary, protocol-buffers

I have to decode BIN file downloaded from a company server to .txt or JSON File format using protocol buffer/compiler (which I have installed). I am using the following decode command in VS Code terminal for the purpose but do not able to deduce the error. I am an automotive systems engineer with no knowledge of coding language and have to decode the BIN file to complete my graduation thesis, so any help will be great full.

Windows Powershell error:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\MyPrograms> C:\protoc-3.14.0-win64\bin\protoc --decode=se.niradynamics.ncs.protobuf.output.RoadLayerTile roadlayertile.proto "< road_roughness_aggregation_23602633.bin >" output.txt
Could not make proto path relative: < road_roughness_aggregation_23602633.bin >: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Hi @VIPLOW17, the error says that it can't find the road_roughness_aggregation_23602633.bin. This might be a dumb question but is it in the C:\protoc-3.14.0-win64\bin\protoc directory you have posted?

Comment: yes, it is in the same directory as protoc.exe

Comment: You should not have quotes around the pipe ( < and > ) operations. Take away the double quotes entirely. To be honest though: using protoc here is very much doing this the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that it can't find the `bin` file, you have to search for it with the *Windows file manager*.

Comment: and how do I do that. the protocol file and the BIN data is in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

You should not have quotes around the pipe ( < and > ) operations, otherwise instead of redirecting stdin / stdout, you are looking for the literal file with > and < in the path, which isn't a thing that can exist. Take away the double quotes entirely.

To be honest though: using protoc here is very much doing this the hard way. If this was me, I'd run the .proto through either protoc or protogen to get a code model that represents the schema in my language of choice, and deserialize into *that*, then run that model through any JSON serializer.

Comment: I have used protoc to get a Javascript code model (generates Javascript file - roadlayertile_pb.js). But since I lack a basic understanding of language I don't have any clue how to use the code model to decode the binary file